# how to calculate MKMapSize from CGSize

Tags: ios, mapkit, coordinate-transformation

I am using MapKit, where I have following `MKAnnotationView` where a red circle of `CGSize(width: 26, height: 26)` is drawn.

[image]

How to calculate size `MKMapSize` from `CGSize` or `MKAnnotationView`?

**Source**:

I got `MKMapView` with several `MKOverlay`s, when user tap any overlay so the `mapView`s region will be changed to that overlay bounds, this works fine, but I need to stop changing region if the tapped coordinate is within the coordinate region where is the `MKAnnotationView` (red circle).

I looked here for other answers but had no luck and tried:

```
let zoomLevel = log2(360 * ((Double(self.frame.size.width) / 256) / mapView.region.span.longitudeDelta)) - 1
MKMapSize(width: 26 * zoomLevel, height: 26 * zoomLevel)
```

Comment: Your red circle is an annotationView or an overlay?

Comment: it is an annotationView

Comment: did you try using `func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView)` delegate method?

Comment: Yes I did try this workaround and determine that it will not work, for the reason that this method will not call when the annotationView's calloutView is open

Answer (score 0):

Here is the `MKMapView` method that does the magic of converting a `CGSize` to `MKCoordinateRegion`:

```
mapView.convert(rect: CGRect, toRegionFrom: UIView?)
```

**Usage:**

```
let customAnnotationSize = CGSize(width: 26, height: 26)
let region = mapView.convert(CGRect(origin: .zero, size: customAnnotationSize), toRegionFrom: mapView)
```

Having a `region` is the big deal, finally I check if the annotation's coordinate is within that `region`.